# Write list of files with relative path, to file, via batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to list all files (with relative path) in a folder with a specific sub-folder, and write that list to a text file. The folder is a network folder so I can not set it as current directory. All this via batch script.

So like this:

Folder structure:

```
\\OtherComputer\MyFiles\libs
--File1.dll
--File2.dll
\\OtherComputer\MyFiles\libs\Editor\
----File3.dll
```

I want to generate a file with the following text:

```
File1.dll
File2.dll
Editor\File3.dll
```

This is how far I have come:

```
SET LibPath=\\OtherComputer\MyFiles\

break >"%LibPath%metadata"
for %%F in (%LibPath%*.*) do (
  echo %%F>>"%LibPath%metadata"
)
for %%F in (%LibPath%Editor\*.*) do (
  echo Editor\%%F>>"%LibPath%metadata"
)
```

But this solution write the full path. I tried this to remove the path:

```
set str=%%F:%LibPath%=%
```

But it does not seem to handle variable `SET` or the `%%F` variable too well inside a for-loop.

Is it even possible? Would like to not have to write a C# executable for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you using the "dir" function?

Comment: If I put /s as parameter to get my sub-folder, it writes the full path. ( Like this: DIR /s /b %LibPath% >%LibPath%metadata )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "dir=\\OtherComputer\MyFiles\"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('dir /s /b /A-d "%dir%"') do ( 
    set "full=%%f"
    echo !full:*%dir%=!
)
```

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, in addition to creating a localized environment, turns on delayed expansions of variables, which allows variables to be modified inside the `for` loop's body and used with their modified values. (see `help set`). Note that in order for a variable to be expanded dynamically, you must enclose it in `!`, not `%`; e.g., `!full!` instead of `%full%`.

  - Note: A side effect of enabling delayed expansion is that *any* `!` characters are interpreted as part of a variable reference, resulting in potentially unwanted removal of `!` chars. from strings, such as in `echo hi!`. To output a *literal* `!` while delayed expansion is enabled, use `^^!` in *unquoted* strings, and `^!` in *double-quoted* strings. Furthermore, literal `^` chars. in double-quoted strings then have to be represented as `^^`.
- `dir /s /b /A-d "%dir%"` lists all files - and files only, due to excluding directories with `/A-d` - in the current subtree (`/s`), as paths only (`b`). Note that using `/s` implies that *full* paths are output.
- `set "full=%%f"` sets aux. variable `full` to the absolute path being processed in the current loop iteration.
- `!full:*%dir%=!` then strips the input dir.'s path from the absolute path using prefix string substitution, leaving the relative path desired (again, see `help set`).

---

Just to contrast this with a **PowerShell** (v3+) solution, which demonstrates how much more advanced PowerShell is compared to `cmd.exe`.:

```
$dir = '\\OtherComputer\MyFiles\'
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $dir).FullName.replace($dir, '')
```

Comment: Awesome! Did not know about the "enabledelayedexpansion" at all, thanks!

Comment: @Mockarutan: My pleasure; I've since added a note re output of literal `!` chars. while delayed expansion is enabled, and also added a PowerShell solution. As you can see, the PowerShell solution is much shorter and much more elegant. If one's background is in batch files, learning PowerShell takes a while, but it's well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way to to this with two bat files:

code1.bat: Looping through all the files in "C:\Mypath"

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s /b C:\Mypath\*.*') do ( 
CALL code2.bat %%G
)
```

code2.bat: removing the main path string

```
SET _var=%1
SET _endbit=%_var:*Mypath\=%
Echo %_endbit%
```

Probably can be done in one file... take a look at http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: ++1 for `dir /s /b` (listing a subtree with absolute paths) and `%_var:*Mypath\=%` (shortest prefix string substitution), but note that inside `%…%` variable references (statically expanded) you're limited to a _literal_ search string.
Using `!…!` variable references (delayed expansion, turned on via `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) allows you to use a statically expanded variable reference in lieu of a literal search string: `!_var:*%MyPath%\=!`
Delayed expansion also allows you to solve the whole problem in a _single_ batch file (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The `xcopy` commmand is capable of returning relative paths. If the `/L` switch is given, nothing is actually copied but all items are listed that would be copied without `/L`. The `pushd` command handles UNC paths correctly (type `pushd /?` in command prompt for details). So the following code snippet should do what you want:

```
@echo off
pushd "\\host\share\folder"
> "\path\to\listfile.txt" xcopy /L /Y /C /I /E ".\*.*" "%TMP%"
popd
```

---

The above code results in each line to be prefixed with `.\`. In addition, it returns a summary line like `# File(s)`. The code below gets rid of all those artefacts:

```
@echo off
pushd "\\host\share\folder"
> "\path\to\listfile.txt" (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('
        xcopy /L /Y /C /I /E "*.*" "%TMP%"
    ') do (
        echo(%%I
    )
)
popd
```

Here I changed the file pattern from `.\*.*` to `*.*` which results in outputs like `Z:rel\path\to\item.ext` (rather than `.\rel\path\to\item.ext`). The `for /F` loop parses the output of `xcopy` and removes everything up to the first `:`, so the drive letter `Z:` is deleted. Since the `:` is a forbidden character for file and directory names, it cannot appear in any of the paths. Since the summary line `# File(s)` does not contain any columns, it is not enumerated by `for /F`.

Comment: ++ for clever use of `xcopy`; the only thing worth noting is that all output paths will be `.\ `-prefixed.

Comment: Thanks! yes, the `.\` prefix is not quite beautiful; however, technically it does not disturb...